# Quantifiers in Tuple Relational Calculus (Existencial and Universal)

Tags: relational-theory, relational-calculus

Suppose this state for the relation schema Company

[image: State Company Relation Schema]

I'm stuck trying to understand **how**, **why** and **when** I should use Quantifiers (Existencial and Universal)

**Examples:**

[image: Example 1]

Here I understand how the existencial is working, all the formula bounded            to him would evaluate to `TRUE`, if at least one of all the possible tuples that `d` can take evaluates to `TRUE` (please tell me if this reasoning is okay)

[image: Example 2]

Here is where things get messy, I don't understand what's actually doing that Universal Quantifier in `NOT(PROJECT(x))`, and why is it using `x` as a tuple in PROJECT in this part `NOT(x.Dnum = 5)`, how we know that `x` is in `PROJECT` ? Is something about the first part with the Universal Quantifier? And why the Universal Quantifier is just bounding `NOT(PROJECT(x))`?